# Vim regex matching multiple results on the same line

Tags: regex, vim

I'm working on a project where I'm converting an implementation of a binary tree to an AVL tree, so I have a few files that contain lines like:

```
Tree<int>* p = new Tree<int>(*t);
```

all over the place.  The goal I have in mind is to use a vim regex to turn all instances of the string `Tree` into the string `AVLTree`, so the line above would become:

```
AVLTree<int>* p = new AVLTree<int>(*t);
```

the regex I tried was `:%s/Tree/AVLTree/g`, but the result was:

```
AVLTree<int>* p = new Tree<int>(*t);
```

I looks to me like when vim finds something to replace on a line it jumps to the next one, so is there a way to match multiple strings on the same line? I realize that this can be accomplished with multiple regex's, so my question is mostly academic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [vi.se]

Comment: The `/g` flag in the regex should have the effect you want. In my case it works fine.

Comment: What does `:set gdefault?` say? (Also, see `:help 'gdefault'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit on this one goes to Marth for pointing this out.  My issue was with vim's `gdefault`.  By default it's set to 'off', which means you need the /g tag to make your search global, which is what I wanted.  I think mine was set to 'on', which means without the tag the search is global, but with the tag the search is not. I found this chart from `:help 'gdefault'` helpful:

```
            command         'gdefault' on   'gdefault' off 
            :s///             subst. all      subst. one
            :s///g            subst. one      subst. all
            :s///gg           subst. all      subst. one
```